# Azure Worker Role ,Serivce bus exception casuing crash

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

"Self healing " that what i trying to do.

i have deployed a worker Role[Single instance ,Small Size] with server 2012. mostly the worker role is assigned to work with service bus.

At a recurring period around 14 to 15 Hours .Worker Role goes in unhealthy state and wont Restart again.

The Exception which are reported in `intelliTrace` are only.

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Service.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetails>
System.TimeoutException
```

[image: intelliTrace]

*Event logs are not reported any thing on these exceptions.*

Can i put `RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle()` at Catch to Recycle if exception occurs. Will this do a Work around.

i haven't able to crash my role on Emulator . so i don't know will this work or not.

Comment: Normally you should let unhandled exceptions propagate out of `Run()` and let the runtime restart your role.

Comment: If you're consistently seeing the timeouts appear after a given period of time, I'd look closely at the resource utilization of the solution. Something may not be releasing properly.